# Python ctypes, char** and DLL

Tags: python, c++, dll, ctypes, cpython

I have a dll function in c++:

```
void get_DLLVersion(CAxClass* obj, char ** pVal);
```

In pVal get_DLLVersion write c string like "1.0.0.1"

In c++ its like:

```
char *strdll = (char*)malloc(50);
    
    get_DLLVersion(tst, &strdll);

    cout << "strdll = "<<strdll<<endl;
```

I need to use this function in python.

The main problem is how to create `char**` and put as 2nd argument of dll function.

I use next code:

```
import ctypes

libc = ctypes.CDLL("AxECR.so")
ecr = libc.create_object() #return CAxClass* obj
print (libc.get_DLLVersion) 
libc.get_DLLVersion.argtypes = [c_void_p, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.POINTER(c_char))]
dll = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.POINTER(c_char))
libc.get_DLLVersion(ecr,dll) #don`t work Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: (1) Explain "don't work". (2) Is there documentation about `get_DLLVersion` which describes what the parameters should be?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Without exactly knowing the problem of the OP you can't know if the referred question solves it.

Comment: @MichaelButscher its fairly reasonable to assume that a function called `get_DLLVersion` is supposed to return a string so `pVal` should be a pointer to a `char` array

Comment: @AlanBirtles The OP needs to create an *instance* of a pointer assuming it is an output parameter and pass `byref` and also set `.restype` of `create_object`.  The duplicate proposed isn’t sufficient

Comment: @AlanBirtles In addition to Mark's comment there are libraries around who may e.g. not provide a null-terminated string via `pVal` but a string of fixed length instead.

Comment: @Mark Tolonen what `.restype` of `create_objec` must be? I add an example with c++ code, maybe it helps to understand how get_DLLVersion works.

Comment: @BRAiNPet is is odd that the parameter is a `char**` since if the user allocated the memory a `char*` is sufficient.  Are you sure that `strdll` maintains its value after the call?

Comment: @BRAiNPet I would declare `class CAxClass(ctypes.c_void_p):  pass` as an opaque pointer to the class, and use `.restype = ctypes.POINTER(CAxClass)` as the return type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listing [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

**Notes**:

- To fix this, a buffer (array) can be created via *create_string_buffer*, then its address passed (via *byref*) to the function

  - An explicit cast (from *char* array to *char* pointer) is required
- For the 1<sup>st</sup> argument, I create singleton *CAxClass* object that is returned by every *createObject* call. I could also have the function creating the new instance, but another one would be then required to destroy it, in order to prevent memory leaks <sup>***(1)***</sup>
- Looking at the way the function is called from *C++*, it just populates the memory at the address given as an argument (if not *NULL*, hopefully).
  In this case, **using a double pointer doesn't make much sense**, as the same goal could be achieved using a simple one (I added another function in the example below to prove this)

Example:

- *dll00.cpp*:

  ```cpp
  #include <cstring>
  #include <iostream>

  #if defined(_WIN32)
  #  define DLL00_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
  #else
  #  define DLL00_EXPORT_API
  #endif

  #define BUF_LEN 50


  class CAxClass {};

  static CAxClass *gObj = new CAxClass();  // nullptr;


  #if defined(__cplusplus)
  extern "C" {
  #endif

  DLL00_EXPORT_API void* createObject();
  DLL00_EXPORT_API void dllVersion(CAxClass *pObj, char **ppVer);
  DLL00_EXPORT_API void dllVersionSinglePtr(CAxClass *pObj, char *pVer);

  #if defined(__cplusplus)
  }
  #endif


  void* createObject() {
      return gObj;
  }


  void dllVersion(CAxClass *pObj, char **ppVer)
  {
      if ((ppVer) && (*ppVer)) {
          strncpy(*ppVer, "1.22.333.4444", BUF_LEN);
      } else {
          std::cout << "C - NULL pointer\n";
      }
  }


  void dllVersionSinglePtr(CAxClass *pObj, char *pVer)
  {
      if (pVer) {
          strncpy(pVer, "55555.666666.7777777.88888888", BUF_LEN);
      } else {
          std::cout << "C - NULL pointer\n";
      }
  }
  ```
- *code00.py*:

  ```py
  #!/usr/bin/env python

  import ctypes as cts
  import sys


  CharPtr = cts.c_char_p  # More generic: cts.POINTER(cts.c_char) ?
  CharPtrPtr = cts.POINTER(CharPtr)

  BUF_LEN = 50

  DLL_NAME = "./dll00.{:s}".format("dll" if sys.platform[:3].lower() == "win" else "so")


  def main(*argv):
      dll = cts.CDLL(DLL_NAME)

      createObject = dll.createObject
      createObject.argtypes = ()
      createObject.restype = cts.c_void_p

      dllVersion = dll.dllVersion
      dllVersion.argtypes = (cts.c_void_p, CharPtrPtr)
      dllVersion.restype = None

      # @TODO - cfati: Testing purposes
      dllVersionSinglePtr = dll.dllVersionSinglePtr
      dllVersionSinglePtr.argtypes = (cts.c_void_p, CharPtr)
      dllVersionSinglePtr.restype = None

      obj = createObject()
      print("Object: {:}".format(obj))

      buf = cts.create_string_buffer(BUF_LEN)
      dllVersion(obj, cts.byref(cts.cast(buf, CharPtr)))
      print("Version: {:}".format(buf.value))

      dllVersionSinglePtr(obj, cts.cast(buf, CharPtr))
      print("Version: {:}".format(buf.value))


  if __name__ == "__main__":
      print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                     64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
      rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
      print("\nDone.\n")
      sys.exit(rc)
  ```

**output**:

> ```
> (qaic-env) [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q075446745]> ~/sopr.sh
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [064bit prompt]> ls
> code00.py  dll00.cpp
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> g++ -fPIC -shared -o dll00.so dll00.cpp
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> ls
> code00.py  dll00.cpp  dll00.so
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> python ./code00.py
> Python 3.8.10 (default, Nov 14 2022, 12:59:47) [GCC 9.4.0] 064bit on linux
>
> Object: 34716928
> Version: b'1.22.333.4444'
> Version: b'55555.666666.7777777.88888888'
>
> Done.
> ```

Might also check:

- [[SO]: C++ & Python: Pass and return a 2D double pointer array from python to c++ (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58262388/4788546) for the use of a double pointer when passing a *2D* array
- [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546) for a common pitfall when working with *CTypes* (calling functions)
- [[SO]: Python ctypes cdll.LoadLibrary, instantiate an object, execute its method, private variable address truncated (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52272969/4788546) for an example of footnote ***#1***