# Fail to release the memory after 2D array multiplication with python ctypes

Tags: multidimensional-array, dll, malloc, ctypes, multiplication

I tried to call functions in DLL with python ctypes module. The functions perform 2D array multiplication successfully and created by C. The following source code would be packaged into "matrixDLL.dll" by Visual Studio 2017.

**C code**

```
//arrayMulti.cpp - will be packaged into "matrixDLL.dll" by Visual Studio 2017.
#include "pch.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern "C" {//prtA: array A, ay: number of rows for A, ax: number of columns for A, prtB: array B
    __declspec(dllexport) double** D2_Dot(double* prtA, int ay, int ax, double* prtB, int by, int bx)
    {
        //allocate memory for 2D array A and assign values
        double** A = (double**)malloc(sizeof(double*)*ay);
        for (int i = 0; i < ay; i++)
            A[i] = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*ax);
        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < ay; i1++)
            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < ax; i2++)
                A[i1][i2] = *(prtA + i1 * ax + i2);
        
        //allocate memory for 2D array B and assign values
        double** B = (double**)malloc(sizeof(double*)*by);
        for (int j = 0; j < by; j++)
            B[j] = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*bx);
        for (int j1 = 0; j1 < by; j1++)
            for (int j2 = 0; j2 < bx; j2++)
                B[j1][j2] = *(prtB + j1 * bx + j2);
            
        //allocate memory for the resulting array C
        double** C = (double**)malloc(sizeof(double*)*ay);
        for (int k = 0; k < ay; k++)
            C[k] = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*bx);

        if (ax != by) {
            printf("Dimension Error!!\n");
        }
        else {
            //find the values of the resulting array C
            for (int i = 0; i < ay; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < bx; j++)
                    for (int k = 0; k < by; k++)
                        C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];

            return C;
        }

    }

    __declspec(dllexport) void free_memDyn(double** ptr, int ny, int nx)
    {
        for (int f = 0; f < ny; f++)
            free(ptr[f]);
        free(ptr);
    }
}
```

Then I call the functions from above DLL with python ctypes module. Please note that I applied POINTER() instead of pointer that’s because the pointer() function creates a new pointer instance, pointing to an object. In contrast, POINTER() is a factory function that creates and returns a new ctypes pointer type.

`matrix.D2_Dot.restype = POINTER(POINTER(c_double * bCol) * aRow)`

**python code**

```
from ctypes import *

matrix = cdll.LoadLibrary('matrixDLL.dll')

A = [[1.0,2.0],[3.0,4.0]]
B = [[0.0,1.0],[2.0,3.0]]
aRow = len(A)
aCol = len(A[0])
ptrA = (c_double*aCol*aRow)()
for i in range(aRow):
  for j in range(aCol):
    ptrA[i][j] = A[i][j]
    
bRow = len(B)
bCol = len(B[0])
ptrB = (c_double*bCol*bRow)()
for i in range(bRow):
  for j in range(bCol):
    ptrB[i][j] = B[i][j]

matrix.D2_Dot.restype = POINTER(POINTER(c_double * bCol) * aRow)
dotRes = matrix.D2_Dot(ptrA,aRow,aCol,ptrB,bRow,bCol)

arrList = [[0.]*bCol for _ in range(aRow)]
for i in range(aRow):
    for j in range(bCol):
        arrList[i][j] = dotRes.contents[i][0][j]

#Return the correct result.
print('arrList[0][0]: ',arrList[0][0])#4.0
print('arrList[0][0]: ',arrList[0][1])#7.0
print('arrList[0][0]: ',arrList[1][0])#8.0
print('arrList[1][1]: ',arrList[1][1])#15.0

#Program crashes at the following  lines.
#matrix.free_memDyn(ptrA, aRow, aCol)
#matrix.free_memDyn(ptrB, bRow, bCol)
#matrix.free_memDyn(ptrA, aRow, aCol)
```

The following lines show the correct results.

[Correct Results:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwTVv.png)

But program starts to crash at this line:

`matrix.free_memDyn(ptrA, aRow, aCol);`

The error message is something like “memory collapse”. I don’t list the details because of different OS and program environment.

If free() function fails , it would cause memory leak. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: `ptrA` and `ptrB` are passed in to your function. No reason to allocate and copy them into `A` and `B` and those allocations are not passed out to be freed anyway…only `C` is.

Comment: Unless this is just for learning should use `numpy` arrays instead and skip all the array copying in Python as well.

Comment: Why deallocating from *C* things allocated in *Python*? Check [\[SO\]: How to pass a 2d array from Python to C? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58735157/4788546), [\[SO\]: C++ & Python: Pass and return a 2D double pointer array from python to c++ (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58262388/4788546) (there are many others),

Comment: Numpy is 3rd party module. In my environment I can't use it. Besides, numpy takes longer time than C code at this operation. It doesn't matter if just do it hundreds times, while it's a deal to do it millions times.