# How to pass a 2d array from Python to C?

Tags: python, c, arrays, pointers, ctypes

I'm trying to pass a 2d array from Python to C, using ctypes.
The array dtype is uint16.
I wrote a simple code just to understand how it works:

C:

```
#include <stdint.h>

__declspec(dllexport) uint16_t Test(uint16_t **arr)
{
     return (arr[5][5]);
}
```

Python:

```
import numpy as np
from ctypes import cdll
import ctypes
from numpy.ctypeslib import ndpointer

_p = ndpointer(dtype=np.uint16, ndim=2, shape=(10, 10), flags='C')
mydll = cdll.LoadLibrary("mydll.dll")
_func = mydll.Test
_func.argtypes = [_p]
_func.restypes = ctypes.c_uint16

data = np.empty([10, 10], dtype=np.uint16)
data[5, 5] = 5
print(_func(data))
```

I get OSError: access violation reading 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
what am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Listing [[SciPy.Docs]: C-Types Foreign Function Interface (numpy.ctypeslib)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.ctypeslib.html) (and [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes) just in case).

This is a exactly like [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011) (a duplicate), it just happens to also involve *NumPy*. 
In other words, you have ***Undefined Behavior***, as *argtypes* must be *CTypes* types (**not** *NumPy*).

Below is a modified version of the your code, that works.

*dll00.c*:

```c
#include <stdint.h>

#if defined(_WIN32)
#  define DLL00_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#  define DLL00_EXPORT_API
#endif


#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
#endif

DLL00_EXPORT_API uint16_t dll00Func00(uint16_t **ppArr);

#if defined(__cplusplus)
}
#endif


uint16_t dll00Func00(uint16_t **ppArr)
{
    return ppArr[5][5];
}
```

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ctypes as ct
import sys

import numpy as np


DLL_NAME = "./dll00.{:s}".format("dll" if sys.platform[:3].lower() == "win" else "so")


def main(*argv):
    UI16Ptr = ct.POINTER(ct.c_uint16)
    UI16PtrPtr = ct.POINTER(UI16Ptr)

    dll00 = ct.CDLL(DLL_NAME)
    dll00Func00 = dll00.dll00Func00
    dll00Func00.argtypes = [UI16PtrPtr]
    dll00Func00.restype = ct.c_uint16


    dim0 = 10
    dim1 = 10
    np_arr_2d = np.empty([dim0, dim1], dtype=np.uint16)

    np_arr_2d[5][5] = 5
    print(np_arr_2d)

    # The "magic" happens in the following lines of code
    ct_arr = np.ctypeslib.as_ctypes(np_arr_2d)
    UI16PtrArr = UI16Ptr * ct_arr._length_
    ct_ptr = ct.cast(UI16PtrArr(*(ct.cast(row, UI16Ptr) for row in ct_arr)), UI16PtrPtr)
    res = dll00Func00(ct_ptr)

    print("\n{0:s} returned: {1:d}".format(dll00Func00.__name__, res))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(item.strip() for item in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    print("NumPy: {0:s}\n".format(np.version.version))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q058727931]> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]> "c:\Install\x86\Microsoft\Visual Studio Community\2017\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64>nul
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> code00.py
> dll00.c
>
> [prompt]> cl /nologo /DDLL dll00.c  /link /NOLOGO /DLL /OUT:dll00.dll
> dll00.c
>    Creating library dll00.lib and object dll00.exp
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> code00.py
> dll00.c
> dll00.dll
> dll00.exp
> dll00.lib
> dll00.obj
>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> NumPy: 1.16.2
>
> [[19760  5277   632     0 32464  5280   632     0   111   114]
>  [  107    92    68   101   118    92    86    69   110   118]
>  [  115    92   112   121    95    48    54    52    95    48]
>  [   51    46    48    55    46    48    51    95   116   101]
>  [  115   116    48    92   108   105    98    92   115   105]
>  [  116   101    45   112    97     5   107    97   103   101]
>  [  115    92   110   117   109   112   121    92   116   101]
>  [  115   116   105   110   103    92    95   112   114   105]
>  [  118    97   116   101    92   110   111   115   101   116]
>  [  101   115   116   101   114    46   112   121     0     0]]
>
> dll00Func00 returned: 5
>
> Done.
> ```

The explanation for all those funky conversions can be found at [[SO]: C++ & Python: Pass and return a 2D double pointer array from python to c++ (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58262388/4788546) (and the referenced [[SO]: Problems with passing and getting arrays for a C function using ctypes (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57299823/4788546)).

Comment: oh man, What you did there is insane and it works, thanks alot.
But lets say instead of returning an uint16, I want to return an uint8 array allocated in C and access it through python as a numpy array?
The array is uint8 but the pointer to the start of the array is 32bit

Comment: If using *CTypes* as a layer between *Python* and *C*, you have be consistent. Any *NumPy*  array you might need, will be constructed (in *Python*) out of *CTypes* array (or buffer). I'm going to repeat myself, but if you know the length of the array you need from *C*, make it an additional (output) parameter of the function instead of a return value (as you won't  have to worry about memory leaks). Remark: the 2 *URL*s at the end of my answer contain the exact piece of information you need. If something isn't clear, feel free to ask another question :)

Comment: ye i got you, thanks alot, allocating the memory in python and passing the array as a parameter is a good idea

Comment: How can i cast ct_ptr back to numpy 2d array?

Comment: Noticed you already asked another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58781199/how-can-i-cast-a-double-pointer-ctype-to-numpy-array.

Comment: Hey man, Im having trouble creating a ctPointer for a 3D numpy array, I have some code but i dont know how to post code block, the code doesn't work tho