# Array of Structures in ctypes python/C

Tags: python, arrays, c, struct, ctypes

After running my code i only can access the first struct of my array, which is defined in the c
function defined in an external file.
I think, that the error is in this line:
`engineLIB.get_files.restype = ctypes.POINTER(file)`
where is only define the restype as "file" instead of an array of files.
I wasnt able to find the syntax for this so i am asking you guys for help.
Many thanks in advance.
Here is my python sourcecode:

```
import ctypes

engineLIB = ctypes.CDLL('./engine.so')

class file(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("name", ctypes.c_char * 250),
        ("path", ctypes.c_char * 250),
        ("fileCnt", ctypes.c_int),
    ]

engineLIB.get_files.restype = ctypes.POINTER(file)
engineLIB.get_files.argtype = ctypes.c_char_p

path = input("Input path: ")
files = engineLIB.get_files(path.encode("utf-8"))

for i in range(2):
    print(files[i].name)
    print(files[i].path)
```

I try to define the restype to an array of structs of the file class defined at the top

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57299823/4788546 contains an example (not for structures, but same principle).

Answer (score 0):

As stated in my comment, looks like is a duplicate of [[SO]: Problems with passing and getting arrays for a C function using ctypes (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57299823/4788546) (although that one is for *double*s instead of structures, and also contains the (extra) **double pointer** (********) stuff), so make sure to read it 1<sup>st</sup>.

I also want to emphasize on [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546) (you have a *typo*: *argtype<s>s</s>*).

I prepared an example of what I guess you're trying to.

*dll00.c*:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#if defined(_WIN32)
#  define DLL00_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#  include <dirent.h>
#  define DLL00_EXPORT_API
#endif

#define MAXPATH 250


typedef struct {
    char name[MAXPATH];
    char path[MAXPATH];
    int cnt;
} File, *PFile;


#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
#endif

DLL00_EXPORT_API PFile getFiles(const char *path, int *pCount);
DLL00_EXPORT_API void dealloc(PFile ptr);

#if defined(__cplusplus)
}
#endif


PFile getFiles(const char *path, int *pCount)
{
    PFile ret = NULL;
    int idx = 0;
#if !defined(_WIN32)
    DIR *pDir = NULL;
    struct dirent *pEntry = NULL;
    if ((!pCount) || (!path)) {
        return ret;
    }
    if (!(pDir = opendir(path))) {
        *pCount = -1;
        return ret;
    }
    *pCount = 0;
    while ((pEntry = readdir(pDir))) {
        ++(*pCount);
    }
    closedir(pDir);

    if (!(pDir = opendir(path))) {
        *pCount = -1;
        return ret;
    }
    *pCount += idx;
    ret = calloc(*pCount, sizeof(File));
    while ((pEntry = readdir(pDir))) {
        strcpy(ret[idx].name, pEntry->d_name);
        strcpy(ret[idx].path, path);
        ret[idx].cnt = idx;
        ++idx;
    }
    closedir(pDir);
#endif
    return ret;
}


void dealloc(PFile ptr)
{
    free(ptr);
}
```

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ctypes as cts
import sys


DLL_NAME = "./dll00.{:s}".format("dll" if sys.platform[:3].lower() == "win" else "so")

MAXPATH = 250  # @TODO - cfati: definitions must match the C ones

class File(cts.Structure):
    _fields_ = (
        ("name", cts.c_char * MAXPATH),
        ("path", cts.c_char * MAXPATH),
        ("cnt", cts.c_int),
    )

FilePtr = cts.POINTER(File)


def main(*argv):
    dll = cts.CDLL(DLL_NAME)
    getFiles = dll.getFiles
    getFiles.argtypes = (cts.c_char_p, cts.POINTER(cts.c_int))
    getFiles.restype = FilePtr
    dealloc = dll.dealloc
    dealloc.argtypes = (FilePtr,)
    dealloc.restype = None


    #path = input("Input path: ")
    path = "."
    count = cts.c_int(0)
    files = getFiles(path.encode(), cts.byref(count))
    print("Path [{:s}] has {:d} entries:".format(path, count.value))
    for idx in range(count.value):
        file = files[idx]
        print("\nName: [{:s}]\nPath: [{:s}]\nCnt: {:d}\n".format(file.name.decode(), file.path.decode(), file.cnt))
    dealloc(files)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Notes**:

- When returning arrays (cause this is what the function returns: an array of structures) in form of pointers (which lack size information), there are ways to signal to the caller the size. I chose the most straightforward one: an additional (output) argument to the function

  - An alternative would be having having an extra entry at the end of the array with some sentinel values for fields (kind of like *NUL* is used to mark the end of a *char**), but I am not such a fan of it
- The *C* code is inefficient, it traverses the directory twice (once to get files count, and the 2<sup>nd</sup> to actually get the data). There are alternatives (growing the array size when it's required), but code would become quite complex, and it's beyond the question scope
- Some more error handling wouldn't hurt
- Although beyond the scope of the question, *getFiles* doesn't return anything on *Win*

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackExchange/StackOverflow/q077368808]> . ~/sopr.sh
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [064bit prompt]> ls
> code00.py  dll00.c
> [064bit prompt]> 
> [064bit prompt]> gcc -fPIC -shared -o dll00.so dll00.c
> [064bit prompt]> ls
> code00.py  dll00.c  dll00.so
> [064bit prompt]> 
> [064bit prompt]> python ./code00.py 
> Python 3.10.12 (main, Jun 11 2023, 05:26:28) [GCC 11.4.0] 064bit on linux
>
> Path [.] has 5 entries:
>
> Name: [.]
> Path: [.]
> Cnt: 0
>
> Name: [..]
> Path: [.]
> Cnt: 1
>
> Name: [code00.py]
> Path: [.]
> Cnt: 2
>
> Name: [dll00.c]
> Path: [.]
> Cnt: 3
>
> Name: [dll00.so]
> Path: [.]
> Cnt: 4
>
> Done.
> ```

Comment: Thank your very much